# Allow me to close the div informing me of creating a job alert

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

Within search jobs there is a link that states:

> Would you like to see more jobs like this?  Create a job alert?

Feature request, allow me to remove this message and cookie it out so that I don't always have this thing sitting there.

Comment: We have an alternative design waiting for dev that will take care of this exact thing. Design team realized this was a suboptimal thing to keep around in the UI all the time :) The job alert work did not make the cut for this release, but should appear in the coming week(s).

Comment: Setting to `status-declined` as this UI elements on the job page is no longer there